# What is wrong with my recessed light wiring?

Tags: electrical

I went to put a retrofit LED lamp in my recessed light fixture.  But after completing it the light does not work. I even put it all back the way it was and still nothing.  Double checked the bulb and it works fine.  When testing to see if I had power I touch the tester to the black line going into the bulb screw socket and when I touch the other probe to the metal housing itself I get a power reading.  I get nothing when touching the black wire and white wire.  Seems something is wrong to me and that the metal housing should not be hot, or am I wrong?

Comment: The metal housing is (or should be) grounded, which is why you measure voltage between hot and the housing. If you get a voltage reading when measuring between the housing and ground, then you have a problem.

Comment: Are you measuring between the black and white wires while the switch is on and a bulb is installed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a voltage reading between hot and ground but not hot and neutral, it means you have an open neutral somewhere between the bulb and the panel.  Since you were playing around in the fixture, that'd be the first place I'd check.  Remove all of the wirenuts and check the quality of the connections, both from the line as well as the socket.  If the fixture has a transformer there will be another set of connections to check (primary and secondary sides).